# apt-get issue: duplicate software sources

Tags: 12.04, apt

I have a problem every time I run `sudo apt-get update`. The following is a output from the terminal:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I need help in resolving the duplicate software source problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Run `sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock` in terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is to check your `sources.list` file at `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Open your `sources.list` file with

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove any duplicates of the lines below that you mentioned:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

(You may **not** have the `deb-src` enabled; that doesn't matter.)

If that is unsuccessful try these two commands below. The first command removes the lock which could be causing the problem, and the second removes your cached lists, but leaves the folder intact. (The lists will be regenerated when you enter `sudo apt-get update`.)

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock  
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

(**Make sure** you type correctly and remove the right files, or use the `-i` (interactive) option instead of the `-f` (force) option with `rm`)

Finally, to check everything's back to normal, type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**NOTE:** The lock error also occurs when `Synaptic` is also running when you try to update and install programs with the command-line, so make sure you are only using one way to update.